# How to do math in VBA in Word?

Tags: vba, variables, math, ms-word

As the 2020 tax season approaches, I'm trying to create a simple macro in Word that will take a few user inputs and populate an email template relating to stimulus checks to send to my clients. The actual macro just opens an info box with spaces for three user inputs. Inside of that box, there is an 'OK' button and a 'Cancel' button. The cancel button just hides the box, and the OK button performs the following:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim taxpayerName As Range
    Set taxpayerName = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("tpName").Range
    taxpayerName.Text = Me.TextBox1.Value
    
    Dim numberOfDep As Range
    Set numberOfDep = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("numDep").Range
    numberOfDep.Text = Me.TextBox3.Value
    
    Dim numberOfDep1 As Integer
    numberOfDep1 = Me.TextBox3.Value
    
    Dim maritalStatus As Range
    Set maritalStatus = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("mStatus").Range
    maritalStatus.Text = Me.TextBox2.Value
    
    Dim maritalStatus1 As Range
    Set maritalStatus1 = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("mStatus1").Range
    maritalStatus1.Text = Me.TextBox2.Value
    
    Dim maritalStatus2 As Range
    Set maritalStatus2 = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("mStatus2").Range
    maritalStatus2.Text = Me.TextBox2.Value
    
    Me.Repaint
    tpInfo.Hide
    
    Dim amount1 As Integer
        If maritalStatus = "single" Then
        amount1 = 1200
        Else
        amount1 = 2400
        End If
    amount1 = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("a1").Range
End Sub
```

I'm trying to check my `maritalStatus` variable for 'single' and assign `amount1` a value of either 1200 or 2400 for the first round of stimulus payments. I then want to insert that value into the Word document at bookmark `a1` that I've created. However, I currently get the runtime error 13 on the last line of my code.

My end goal is to take `amount1` and add it to a new variable (`depAmount1`) that would multiply $500 by the number of dependents, which should be stored in `numberOfDep1`. So a single taxpayer with 1 child would result in a total of $1,700. Then I would repeat the code with minor tweaks for the second round of stimulus payments and finally add the two totals together for the grand total.

Thanks in advance, any help would be greatly appreciated.

> [image: 1]

Comment: `a simple macro in Word that will take a few user inputs and populate an email template relating to stimulus checks to send to my clients` - sounds like the introduction of every Word VBA malware ever. You should probably look into [fields](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/list-of-field-codes-in-word-1ad6d91a-55a7-4a8d-b535-cf7888659a51) instead.

Comment: I should add that I will be the user filling out the input box questions. Not sure if that changes the malware comment. I will look at their prior year return, enter their name, filing status and # of dependents to then populate the document. I would then copy and paste as a new email to the client. I will happily look into fields if you still think that is best. Was just hoping to avoid typing the same email hundreds of times this spring. Thanks!

Comment: To see how to do this and a wide range of other calculations in Word, check out my **Microsoft Word Field Maths Tutorial**, at https://www.msofficeforums.com/word/38720-microsoft-word-field-maths-tutorial.html or http://www.gmayor.com/downloads.htm#Third_party

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the core of your question is the error on your last line of code,  I think you're probably getting it because you're trying to assign a string from your bookmark to the amount1 variable, which is specified as an Integer, and I think you want to do the opposite, put the value into the document.  Reversing your line of code should do the trick.

```
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("a1").Range = amount1
```

Comment: That fixed it, thank you very much! This is all relatively new to me if you can't tell.

Comment: Can I add a dumb follow up question and ask how to format my variable amount1 to have a comma and show up as 1,200 or 2,400? I've tried the following with no luck:

amount1 = 1200.NumberFormat = "Standard" and also
Format(amount1 = 1200, "Standard")

Comment: The syntax of the format command is format(<number>, "format") where there are all sorts of different things you can do (this seems like a decent intro: [VBA Format Function](https://vbaf1.com/functions/format/). But for your question, just go with format(amount1, "#,000"). That will work for values below 1,000 as well. "Standard" is also a valid format, but it will give you 2 decimal places.

Comment: `Format` results in a `String` so you would use it when inserting the amount into the document, i.e. `ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("a1").Range.Text = Format(amount1, “#,000”)`